# Google Maps в IOS 6

Tags: google-maps, карты, xcode, ios

В последнем Xcode 4.5 для IOS 6 фреймворк мапкит предлагает уже эпловские карты. Можно ли каким-то образом работать из этой версии Xcode c гугловскими картами? Стоит задача собрать гео-апп на картах Google для IOS 5.
Если нет то как бы Вы решили этот вопрос? В голову пока приходит только установка в виртуалку  Lion'а и в него соответственно более ранней версии  Xcode.

Comment: Если быть более конкретным: фреймворк обращается к тем картам которые установлены на устройстве, и с одинаковым успехом будет выполняться на устройстве с любыми картами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верно подметил, на iphone`ах с ios 5 на борту, будут отображаться карты гугла,
на ios 6 же - карты от apple. Если ты делаешь проект исключительно под ios 5, то и карты
там будут гугловские, от xcode это не зависит.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!